# Error setting up Protege 5.2.1 with Eclipse and Maven on Java 8 (in Linux)

Tags: eclipse, java-8, maven-2, apache-felix, protege

Trying to Set up protege 5.2.1 in linux environment. Followed steps from the link https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/wiki/Setup-in-Eclipse

Maven Build is successful. OSGi framework started but error in org.apache.felix.main.jar file. Please see the error details below. Can some body please advise ?

Error starting file:/home/user/protege/protege-desktop/target/protege-5.2.1-SNAPSHOT-platform-independent/Protege-5.2.1-SNAPSHOT/bundles/protege-editor-core.jar

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.protege.editor.core.application [4].
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2204) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2072) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304) [org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:4362) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2149) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: null
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.(SwingUtilities.java:1758) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1833) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1696) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getWindowForComponent(JOptionPane.java:1637) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.createDialog(JOptionPane.java:956) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.createDialog(JOptionPane.java:918) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at org.protege.editor.core.log.LogManager.(LogManager.java:44) ~[na:na]
at org.protege.editor.core.ProtegeApplication.(ProtegeApplication.java:82) ~[na:na]
```

... 11 common frames omitted
The OSGi framework has been started